# how to export 2 different functions from one js file into another Js file in Protractor

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Kindly help me to find the solution just wanted know how to export 2 functions into spec or in another js file. pls check my below code for ur reference. This is some agentdetails.js file. I want to call the below functions in spec(both the functions) some times i use only one

```
var AddAgent = function()                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
var AGP = require('D:/Automation/ServCloud/PageObjects/AgentDetailsObjects.js');                                   
var Login = require('D:/Automation/ServCloud/Test DATA/TestData.json');                                            
                                                                                                              AGP.Agent.click();                                                                                                 
AGP.AddAgentbtn.click();                                                                                           
AGP.Supervisor.click();                                                                                            
AGP.AgtSave.click();                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                   
module.exports = new AddAgent();     

var EditAgent = function()                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                  

    var AGP = require('D:/Automation/ServCloud/PageObjects/AgentDetailsObjects.js');                               
    var Login = require('D:/Automation/ServCloud/Test DATA/TestData.json');                                        

    AGP.AgentEdit.click();                                                                                         
    AGP.AgtSave.click();                                                                                           
    browser.sleep(3000);                                                                                           
    var alertDialog = browser.switchTo().alert();                                                                                                                                                                         }                                                                                                                  
module.exports = new EditAgent();
```

I have tried like this. (FYI - I can make this into one function and i can call it but i wanted to split into 2 functions and call both in one spec separately so that i can comment which ever is not required at times

```
    it('Add Agent Details', function() 
    { 
    var aa = require('D:/Automation/ServCloud/Actions/AgentAction.js');
aa.AddAgent();

aa.EditAgent(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don`t think it is possible,
You can do:

```
varr AggentFunctions = function() {

    this.AddAgent = function(){
    //some code           
    };         


    this.EditAgent = function(){
    //some code   
    };  
};
module.exports = AggentFunctions;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var agentsFuncs = require('yourAgentFile');
var agents = new agentsFuncs;

//and call what you want
agents.AddAgent();
agents.EditAgent();
```

Comment: many thanks @cvakiitho this is not a bad option i have used ur suggestions so that if i don't need the edit agent i can comment. one more query hw can i use the variable from AddAgent or EditAgent function. if at all i need it use it.